# postgres unable to get query filter by time and date viz

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like this:-

```
select id,created_at from tickets where created_at between '2020-01-23' and '2020-01-25';
 id  |         created_at         
-----+----------------------------
 297 | 2020-01-24 06:27:29.892841
 298 | 2020-01-24 06:57:51.710571
 299 | 2020-01-24 08:00:58.168503
 300 | 2020-01-24 08:41:27.063816
```

I want result to be filter by time i.e within that date range I want record created between 5 to 7

expected result:-

```
 id  |         created_at         
-----+----------------------------
 297 | 2020-01-24 06:27:29.892841
 298 | 2020-01-24 06:57:51.710571
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the `timestamp` column to `time` and keep your logic.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tickets ( id int, created_at timestamp);
INSERT INTO tickets VALUES
 (297 ,' 2020-01-24 06:27:29.892841'),
 (298 ,' 2020-01-24 06:57:51.710571'),
 (299 ,' 2020-01-24 08:00:58.168503'),
 (300 ,' 2020-01-24 08:41:27.063816');


SELECT id, created_at FROM tickets
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2020-01-23' and '2020-01-25'
AND created_at::TIME BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '07:00:00';

 id  |         created_at         
-----+----------------------------
 297 | 2020-01-24 06:27:29.892841
 298 | 2020-01-24 06:57:51.710571
(2 Zeilen)
```

Using `extract(hour ...)` is also an alternative, but you lose the ability to consider minutes in your time interval, e.g. `05:42:00`-`06:55:00`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Postgres' date function `extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

```
select id,created_at 
from tickets 
where 
    created_at between '2020-01-23' and '2020-01-25'
    and extract(hour from created_at) between 5 and 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run some query like this

```
select id,created_at 
from tickets 
where created_at between '2020-01-23' and '2020-01-25' 
and created_at::time between '#05:00:00#' and '#07:00:00#';
```